# Fiddler Statistics for WCF request Java Client - .NET Server

Tags: java, .net, wcf, protocol-buffers, fiddler

I am having WCF Service hosted in a Windows Service. The serialization is made with Protobuf, and using .NET 4.5 (no async/await).
The service behaviour:
   [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,  and is using HttpBasicBinding on port 8773.

I am making 100 requests at the same time from a Java Client using CXF (latest version 3.0.3), all on different threads. The CXF is using the HTTPConduit so the requests are made synchronous, one by one.

I have monitored the time it takes from java for a request, and it says around 2200ms the first calls, than the raises because of the CXF  syncronous calls,2200ms,2229ms,2238ms,2233ms,3139ms,3662ms,4235ms,4233ms,4257ms,4287ms,4288ms,4737ms,5268ms and after that lowers and gets back to 2200ms.
. In .NET, the server, it process the requests in around 2000 ms, all calls.

But in Fiddler, I am seeing this (the example below is the first call 2200ms):

```
ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:      11:18:46.674
ClientBeginRequest:   11:18:46.674
GotRequestHeaders:    11:18:46.674
ClientDoneRequest:    11:18:46.674
Determine Gateway:    0ms
DNS Lookup:           0ms
TCP/IP Connect:       0ms
HTTPS Handshake:      0ms
ServerConnected:      11:18:45.090
FiddlerBeginRequest:  11:18:46.674
ServerGotRequest:     11:18:46.674
ServerBeginResponse:  11:18:51.382
GotResponseHeaders:   11:18:51.382
ServerDoneResponse:   11:18:51.382
ClientBeginResponse:  11:18:51.382
ClientDoneResponse:   11:18:51.382

Overall Elapsed:      0:00:04.707
```

Java statistics:

```
49  11:18:46 649    2200ms
```

.NET Statistics:

```
Entering, 11:18:46.748 Exiting, 11:18:48.831
```

All it's running on the same box, and  to monitor with fiddler I am using this arguments -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 . And fiddler listens on port 8888.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's not really clear what question you're asking here.